# How can I avoid passing a lot of parameters into a nested function?

Tags: function, rust, nested, arguments

I have read that there is no way how to pass all outer local parameters to a nested function, but maybe there are some hacks to do it anyway? How can I avoid passing a lot of parameters into this function, for example:

```
let var1 = 5;
let var2 = 12.2;
let var3 = bar();
let var4 = tar() * var1;
// etc ... a lot of variables ...
fn foo() {
    // want to have var1, var2, var3, var4 ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html):

```
fn main() {
    let var1 = 5;
    let var2 = 12.2;
    let foo = || {
        var1 as f64 + var2
    };
    println!("foo(): {}", foo()); // prints "foo(): 17.2"
}
```